# Running an external program through a tkinter button in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Im new to programming, and really only doing this for a school project. Im trying to make a GUI that has a series of buttons that when pressed will run a specific emulator. When I try to run this I get a error saying "z26" is undefined. Im not quite sure on how to actually define it.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self._button = Button(self, text = "Atari", command = self._openFile)
        self._button.grid()
    def _openFile(self):
        os.startfile(z26.exe)

root = Tk()
root.title("Arcade")
root.geometry("200x85")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using x26.exe as a literal, and it is getting evaluated as though it were part of the Python program itself.

Instead, put the path with quotequotations, to make it a string:

```
os.startfile('path/z26.exe')
```

See also the Python documentation for [os.startfile(path[, operation])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.startfile).